How to find memory address of a function which isn't called in main, but declared and defined outside main in gdb
tl,tr: Find memory address of an uncalled function, without having source code(or having function name) in gdb.
Issue: given a source code given to me, which looks like this:
#include<stdio.h>

func foo1(){                               => I want memory address of this function
//smth here
}

int main(){
//smth here           =>in any way this doesn't calls or sets pointer or anything related to foo1.
}


Obviously, this looks easy by info function foo1
.
But here's the catch I want to pretend that I do not have source code, just executable of this, so only part inside main would be seen right? A user who is going to run executable will not really know there exists a function foo1.(As main and foo1 has no connection as such)
So using gdb only how can I find memory address of foo1?
What section of memory layout it may be contained?
(I checked in .text .data )
by
info files,
disassemble <memory-address .text>
disassemble 0x00007ff730c4a000
Dump of assembler code for function __mingw_winmain_nShowCmd:
   0x00007ff730c4a000 <+0>:     or     (%rax),%al
   0x00007ff730c4a002 <+2>:     add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ff730c4a004 <+4>:     add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ff730c4a006 <+6>:     add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ff730c4a008 <+8>:     add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ff730c4a00a <+10>:    add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ff730c4a00c <+12>:    add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ff730c4a00e <+14>:    add    %al,(%rax)
End of assembler dump.

disassemble <memory-address .data>
disassemble 0x00007ff730c31000
Dump of assembler code for function __mingw_invalidParameterHandler:
   0x00007ff730c31000 <+0>:     ret
End of assembler dump.

similarly, I disassembled entry point, but still no clue.
disassemble  0x7ff730c314e0
Dump of assembler code for function mainCRTStartup:
   0x00007ff730c314e0 <+0>:     sub    $0x28,%rsp
   0x00007ff730c314e4 <+4>:     mov    0x1aaa5(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ff730c4bf90 <.refptr.mingw_app_type>
   0x00007ff730c314eb <+11>:    movl   $0x0,(%rax)
   0x00007ff730c314f1 <+17>:    call   0x7ff730c31190 <__tmainCRTStartup>
   0x00007ff730c314f6 <+22>:    nop
   0x00007ff730c314f7 <+23>:    nop
   0x00007ff730c314f8 <+24>:    add    $0x28,%rsp
   0x00007ff730c314fc <+28>:    ret
End of assembler dump.

by python-gdb api i tried this:
   for symbol in gdb.objfiles():
    #print(gdb.symtab)
    print(symbol.lookup_global_symbol)

I read docs here
which resulted in:
 source gdb_script.py

<built-in method lookup_global_symbol of gdb.Objfile object at 0x000001E5EF7F5030>
<built-in method lookup_global_symbol of gdb.Objfile object at 0x000001E5EF7F5170>
<built-in method lookup_global_symbol of gdb.Objfile object at 0x000001E5EF7F51C0>
<built-in method lookup_global_symbol of gdb.Objfile object at 0x000001E5EF7F5210>
<built-in method lookup_global_symbol of gdb.Objfile object at 0x000001E5EF7F5260>

new question arised, What exactly is this now? Addresses looks different, it has left me more confused now.(I want to know what exactly above means).
I want to do this with gdb, no other tools.

Im a newbie to reverse engineering, please let it go, if something is not cleared from my side. :(


In ecexutable tere is no foo1 too. No symbols. It is present only in the debug info

If foo1 is never called, a smart linker could even remove the function from the executable.

okay got it, but Im confused then why doing info functions foo1 gives me valid memory address? As you said linker removes it from executable? @Barmar

I said it could, not that it necessarily would.

If you don't strip debugging symbols, gdb can look it up.

okay okay, but symbols aren't stripped. symbols are attached but this foo1 has no relation with main, in main i cant look up address of foo1 like normally if there was function call(I can see addresses of other function calls in main as i called them inmain[user-defined, functions in header files]). @Barmar

@0___________ there are symbols this isnt stripped binary, i didnt got you while compiling process wouldnt it conside foo1 too? Why wouldnt there be no symbol or trace? Where in debug info? I assume gdb is debugger?

Not exactly sure what symbol.lookup_global_symbol is supposed to do here, you probably want to try symbol.value() instead (with the () parentheses).

@ssbssa in docs they mentioned this: Function: Objfile.lookup_global_symbol (name [, domain])
Search for a global symbol named name in this objfile. So i left arguments empty and run my script in gdb which resulted in above output(which is confusing as it is about exactly)[My theory is if i cant find function anywhere maybe it's global? So its global symbol im not sure], and objfiles dont have value attribute AttributeError: 'gdb.Objfile' object has no attribute 'value'

If you do for symbol in Symtab.global_block(), you don't need to call lookup_global_symbol, because you already got the symbols from the block iterator. And even if you want to keep the arguments empty, you still have to keep the () parentheses, without them it doesn't call the function, and instead give you these built-in method objects you got.

@ssbssa regarding python script, i tried     for symbol in gdb.Symtab.global_block():
TypeError: unbound method Symtab.global_block() needs an argument, which is weird now cause docs don't state it to give arguments to attribute global_block. https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Symbol-Tables-In-Python.html

You first need a Symtab object on which you then can call .global_block(). And if your goal is to get all global symbols of all symtabs, then I don't think this is possible with gdb-python, as there is currently no way to iterate through all symtabs.

what does nm -a executable produce ?

@ssbssa sorry, for my vagueness and laziness, i beleive by creating a object means doing this import gdb
block = gdb.Symtab
for symbol in block:
print(symbol.global_block()) , i think that too.

@ticktalk i did tried with nm already in my linux machine, it does gives me valid address along with function name foo specified. I was just looking for an alternate route too, like in my binary symbols arent stripped but what if they are? Ik i just sound weird but I'm doing this for part of research and curiosity of RE and binary exploitation, where obviously exe/elfs are stripped most of the times.
